# mongodb find: how to use a variable regexp inside $where?

Tags: regex, mongodb, express, where-clause

I have a nodejs express web with a mongo db with

```
const AuthorSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 100 },
    family_name: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 100 },
    date_of_birth: { type: Date },
    date_of_death: { type: Date },
});
```

I want to search for an author using a regexp over the first_name + family_name. In other words,
given we have an author with:
...
first_name: 'Alessandro'
family_name: 'Manzoni'
...
I want to match it using all of the search strings:

'Alessandro' or 'ale' or 'manzo' or 'alessandro manzoni' or 'Manzoni Alessandro'

so I wrote this:

```
const searchRegex = new RegExp(req.body.search_text, 'i');  
Author.find({ $where: 
    function() {
        return (searchRegex.test(this.first_name + " " + this.family_name) 
            || searchRegex.test(this.family_name + " " + this.first_name) )
    } 
},"_id").exec(function (err, list_authors) {
```

and I got:

```
MongoServerError: Executor error during find command :: caused by :: ReferenceError: searchRegex is not defined :
@:2:33
```

I tried using a $let clause but all I've achieved is getting all of the authors id in the results list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this (and avoiding `$where` which is very inefficient):

This query get the first and family names concatenated and do the regex match on it.

If there is a match in the regex (the result is `true`) the document will be returned. Otherwise it doesn't.

```
Author.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [
      {
        "$regexMatch": {
          "input": {
            "$concat": [
              "$first_name",
              " ",
              "$family_name"
            ]
          },
          "regex": yourStringRegexHere,
          "options": "i"
        }
      },
      true
    ]
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/adgaHOlWD7j)

Comment: I totally agree the `$where` should be avoided. This solution will still do a full index/collection scan though, so OP may want to reconsider their schema and overall approach

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, your answer works perfectly. I added a $or to search also in `family_name + " " + first_name` and deleted the options line because they are in the regex. So the final code is:

```js
Author.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$regexMatch": {
              "input": {
                "$concat": [
                  "$first_name",
                  " ",
                  "$family_name"
                ]
              },
              "regex": searchRegex
            }
          },
        true
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "$expr": {
      "$eq": [
        {
          "$regexMatch": {
            "input": {
              "$concat": [
                "$family_name",
                " ",
                "$first_name"
              ]
            },
            "regex": searchRegex
          }
        },
        true
      ]
    }
  },                    
]},"_id").exec(callback);
```

Really a lot of code, but it works...